# Criar objetos após resposta do servidor externo via API

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api

É o seguinte, eu criei uma API em php que gera um Json. [O LINK é esse](http://qsmidia.com.br/androidTeste/) para quem quiser visualizar.

Eu consegui acessar o link e resgatar as informações, pois usei um Toast para mostra-las. Mas por algum motivo, que eu desconheço, eu não consigo usar essas informações para criar objetos.

Segue abaixo a função que estou usando dentro do MainActivity:

```
listaHome = new ArrayList<>();

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://qsmidia.com.br/androidTeste/", null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray postagens = response.getJSONArray("anotacao");
                for (int i = 0; i < postagens.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject post = postagens.getJSONObject(i);
                    // aqui ele deveria adicionar a lista
                    listaHome.add(new Anotacoes(post.getString("id_anotacao"), post.getString("titulo"), post.getString("texto")));
                    // aqui ele mostra o título no toast (2 registros)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), post.getString("titulo"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Erro: ", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro exception > " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro de resposta > " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    );
    request.add(objectRequest);
```

Essa `listaHome` está declarada como `private List<Anotacoes> listaHome;` dentro da mesma classe da função.

Antes que me perguntem eu inseri no manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

E nas dependências:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

O `List<Anotacoes> listaHome` fica vazio, ou seja, nenhum objeto é inserido.

Uma observação: Quando eu TENTO inserir manualmente DENTRO DO `TRY`, também NÃO É INSERIDO. Desta forma:

```
try {
       JSONArray postagens = response.getJSONArray("anotacao");
       for (int i = 0; i < postagens.length(); i++){
          JSONObject post = postagens.getJSONObject(i);

          // aqui ele deveria inserir, mas não insere
          listaHome.add(new Anotacoes("1","Teste 1", "texto de teste 1"));

          // aqui ele mostra o título no toast (2 registros)
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), post.getString("titulo"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     }
```

**Porque isso ocorre?**
**Como posso criar objetos e inserir em uma lista com as variáveis que são recuperadas através da API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer preencher a sua lista e em seguida fazer uso dela. Porém, o preenchimento e o uso deveriam ocorrer um em seguida do outro. Acredito que no seu código isso não está acontecendo.

Primeiramente você está declarando a lista:

```
listaHome = new ArrayList<>();
```

em seguida declara sua requisição HTTP:

```
JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( ... );
request.add(objectRequest);
```

e provavelmente em seguida tenta utilizar a lista (essa parte não consta no código que você incluiu na pergunta, mas estou deduzindo).

Tenha em mente que a requisição HTTP está sendo declarada mais não vai ser executada imediatamente. Por isso se você quiser usar a lista em seguida a essa declaração terá que esperar ela executar e ao final dessa execução fazer uso da lista, e não tentar usar imediatamente após a declaração.

Em outras palavras, o correto seria você mover o código que faz uso da lista para logo depois do bloco `for` que está preenchendo a lista.

Comment: Entendi. A requisição HTTP é executada aqui `request.add(objectRequest);` certo?

Comment: Aí ela é posta na fila de execução. Quando esta linha `request.add(objectRequest);` terminar de executar a requisição ainda não terá sido executada. Portanto se o código que vier abaixo dessa linha estiver esperando que a lista esteja preenchida, ela não estará. A execução será feita mais tarde (assincronamente). O lugar correto de fazer uso da lista preenchida é logo abaixo do blogo `for`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estava queimando os "fuzivi" aqui.